# Inductor calculation for DC to DC converter

Tags: pwm, dc-dc-converter

How can I calculate the value and characteristics of inductor in a DC to DC converter?

[image]

Comment: What does the datasheet for the converter say?

Comment: datasheets will specify clearly.it's just inductor's V-I equation: Voltage across inductor = L (di-ripple)/dt(on time/off time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really great walk-through on DC-DC converter (Buck topology specifically) design calculations can be found at this [Microchip Technology's web seminar slideshow](http://simonthenerd.com/files/smps/SMPSBuckDesign_031809.pdf). The seminar covers these important topics:

1. Calculate the required inductor
2. Calculate the output capacitor requirements
3. Select the input capacitor
4. Select the diode
5. Choose the MOSFET
6. Calculate the converter Efficiency

You need to know things like the input voltage, intended output voltage, acceptable input and output ripple voltage for your system/converter IC, and current requirements, as well as the switching frequency of your DC-DC converter IC.

Comment: Yes but all requirements it's depended by us. I want to choose all requirements randomly for inductor calculation

Comment: Use an excel spreadsheet for the input parameters and the formulas. That's what I did :)